# How to access the name only from visual force component

Tags: visualforce-component

I have Visual Force Component:

```
<apex:component controller="myController1" access="global"> 
<p /> 
<apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}</apex:outputLink> <br /> 
<apex:outputLabel value="{!userName}" id="someId" /> 
<apex:outputLabel value="{!userPhone}" id="someId2" /> 
</apex:component>
```

**How to access the username only from visual force component to Visual force template in email alert using Work flow Rule in salesforce ,please Anyone Guide me for the Answer**

**I have tried in Vf template:**

```
<br>User <c:ant id = "someId" value = "{!userName}"/></br>
```

**but it is showing error like:
Error: Unsupported attribute value in**

**How to Rectify the Error Please anyone Guide me for the Answer**

Answer (score 0):

the body of an  tag can also specify the attributes that can be passed in to the custom component when it’s used in a Visualforce page or template. The values of such attributes can then be used directly in the component so if you want to access value of username you need to first define component attribute as show below.

```
<apex:component controller="myController1" access="global"> 
 <apex:attribute name="userName" description="This is username." type="String" required="true"/>
<apex:attribute name="userPhone" description="This is phone." type="String" required="true"/>
<p /> 
<apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}</apex:outputLink> <br /> 
<apex:outputLabel value="{!userName}" id="someId" /> 
<apex:outputLabel value="{!userPhone}" id="someId2" /> 
</apex:component>
```

Once this is done you can assign value as shown below

```
 <br>User <c:ant username="{!$User.username}" userPhone="{!$User.phone}"/></br>
```

Please read detailed document here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_comp_cust_elements_attributes.htm

Comment: after updating the code in vf template it is showing error:Error: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.userName' @Himanshu

Comment: are you there? @Himanshu

Comment: from where you are reading your userName in template.

Comment: in body @Himanshu

Comment: please post your template code by editing your question.

Comment: if you are trying to access current user. please use {!$User.username}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48603/discussion-between-himanshu-and-user36188).

Comment: when you need only username why you are using component, can't you use username using {!User.username}?

Comment: it is not displaying both the combination of firstname and lastname,Can you suggest the answer using Apex class Please @Himanshu

Comment: It is Not Possible ah? @hIMANSHU

Comment: check follow up discussion in chat

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149083/how-do-i-put-dynamic-context-in-the-subject-attribute-of-an-email-template?noredirect=1 can you answer for this @Himanshu